# Analytic isomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

I am going to ask your help on one of my homework problems.

> Let $f$ be an analytic isomorphism of $D(0,1)$, that is, $f\in\textrm{Iso}(D(0,1),U)$. Show that if $D(f(0),R)⊂U$, then $R\leq|f'(0)|$.

So what I figured out so far:

$f$ analytic in $D(0,1)$ and for $f:D(0,1) \longrightarrow U$ there exists an analytic function $g$ defined on $U$ (i.e., $g:U \longrightarrow D(0,1)$) such that $g(f(z))=z$ for every $z \in D(0,1)$.

We also know if $f∈\textrm{Iso}(D(0,1),U)$ then $f^{-1}∈\textrm{Iso}(U,D(0,1))$. Since $f(0)$ is in $U$ and we assume $D(f(0),R)⊂U$ then I do not know how I should continue. Can you please help me to find the correct steps that take me to the answer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of Schwarz Lemma. You have $ f^{-1}: U\to D $. Instead of $ U $ just consider $ f^{-1}: D(f(0),R)\to D(0,1) $. So by Schwarz Lemma, $ |\frac {d}{dz} f^{-1}(z) |$ at $ z=f(0) $ is $\le\frac {1}{R} $. So $ \frac {1}{|f'(0)|}\le \frac {1}{R} $. So done.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer but i have some questions. Should not we have a map D(0,1)..>D(0,1) in

Comment: just consider the map $ g:D(0,1)\to D(0,1) $ given by $ g(z)=f^{-1}(f(0)+Rz) $ and apply Schwarz Lemma.

Comment: thanks. it is very clear now.